# How long do El-Aurians live?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek: The Next Generation, the bartender in Ten Forward is the enigmatic Guinan, a member of a race called the El-Aurian. While it is generally known that her race is long lived, in the episode *[Times Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow_%28TNG_episode%29)* it is shown that Guinan visited Earth in 1891, at which time she looked relatively the same age as she did in the 24th century. This would have made her at least 500 years old by the 24th century. So how long do the El-Aurian actually live?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_races), "well over 700 years", but hopefully a more specific answer can be found.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any specific information regarding the maximum or average lifespan of an [El-Aurian](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/El-Aurian). Of the known [El-Aurians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/El-Aurians) (some never appearing onscreen), the oldest appears to be [Guinan's father](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Unnamed_El-Aurians):

> Guinan's father was an El-Aurian male born sometime **before** the 17th century. He was described as alive and well in the year 2369. ([TNG](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_The_Next_Generation): ["Rascals"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rascals_%28episode%29)) (*emphasis added by me*)

This would place his youngest possible age (if born in 1600) at 769. Assuming Guinan's father represents an average El-Aurian, I would say an El-Aurian lifespan is, at minimum, almost 800 years.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say yes at least 800 minimum but maximum maybe 1000 even 1100 years. That means Guinan (our beloved El-Aurian) would be dead in the 28th century.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?