# How old is Guinan in Star Trek: TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-generations

How old is Guinan in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*?

[This post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9401/how-long-do-el-aurians-live) gives an age for her father, but not for her.

She shows up on Earth back in 1893 in San Francisco in the two-part episode, *Time's Arrow*. She also shows up in the movie, *Star Trek: Generations*, which was set back in Captain Kirk's time. Neither of those gives her age.

Looking for a canon answer here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can't find an exact age, but with some assumptions it can be narrowed down. In Rascals (ST:TNG season 6), set in 2369, we have the following conversation:

> "Look at these fragments. They're… they're very nearly in perfect condition, and yet they're seven hundred years old."
>
> "So is my father."
>
> — Picard and Guinan

700 may not be a precise figure, but assuming Guinan is rounding, he's nearer 700 than 800. If we also assume he didn't have children before age 20 (again, nothing to confirm but a life expectancy of centuries – seems plausible). This makes her 730 as an upper bound. As @ruakh points out in the comments, if she was 700+ herself, she would likely use herself as the comparator and not her father, so she's under 700.

In 1893 she is an adult and not on her own world. She comes across as having some life experience; even with the knowledge of an advanced race she doesn't seemed fazed by the experience. This makes her at least 500 by the time of TNG.

Non-canon novel 'The buried age' https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Buried_Age suggests she is on Earth after spending her 'early 100s' travelling – this would put the lower estimate at around 600; this also seems more in keeping with her personality and experience, but I can't find a canon reference.

Best estimate 600–700.

Comment: Guinan's mother is told to be about 100 years younger than her father. Guinan herself must have been born after her mother became a full grown adult herself, so I would lower your estimation by 100 years. Which would be in line with my own :)

Comment: Interesting- I can find that statement on Memory Alpha, but the transcript for the episode it references doesn't seem to make that statement? Agree that if verified it would drop the upper bound to the 570-670 range.

Comment: I have no reference other than what is reported by Memory Alpha. Anyway, even if one considers only the age of her father, I think that for a species that could live for many centuries, having children at 20 would be probably a bit early. If she was not explicitly seen as an adult in late 1800's, I would be tempted to believe that she could be born not earlier than her parent's 100~120 birthdays. But in the end, whichever the estimation, very loosely she could be considered to be around 600 years old, with a certain grade of uncertainty.

Comment: I agree with your thinking, and it fits with the novel I found referenced. Suspect there may not be anything more detailed or precise.

Comment: I think that "So is my father" already implies that Guinan herself is not 700 years old -- if she were, she would just say "So am I."

Comment: It also implies that her father is in excellent health, great condition at nearly 700 years old.  This tells us something about life expectancy and aging in appearance.

Comment: Anyway Memory Alpha reports her own birthdate to be "sometime before the late 19th century", this seems to imply that she was not born earlier than this exact century.

Comment: I think that's just based on the fact she is known to be alive in the late 19th century - it puts an absolute limit on how young she could be.

Comment: @Sekhemty We have no idea how long her species takes to reach childbearing age.  We can't simply assume that it happens at a proportionally equivalent time to humans.  For all we know they could reach full adulthood at 200 years or 2 years.  We just don't know enough about them to even begin to guess, since she's the only one we ever meet.  (Other than some flashbacks I think?)

Comment: I chose this answer because it contains quotes from a TNG episode and I asked for canon sources. It also mentions a non-canon source as supporting material, but I don't think that helps the answer. The answer below of "about 550 years" is not based on canon sources but on links to a fandom wiki.

Answer (score 12):

### About 550 years old.

Memory alpha gives two loose timeframes for the birthdates of her parents: [her father](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_El-Aurians#Guinan.27s_father) was born before the 17th century, while [her mother](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_El-Aurians#Guinan.27s_mother) before the 18th.

Guinan herself is told to have been born "[sometime before the late 19th century](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Guinan#Early_life)", and we see her as a full-grown adult in 1893.

Given the birthdate of her mother (the youngest of her parents) during the 1700's and Guinan being adult at the end of the 1800's, if we take a middle point between these two dates we can loosely assume her to be born in the early 1800's.

Given that *Star Trek: The Next Generation* is set during the 2360's, the difference between this date and the early 1800's is more or less 550, which can be assumed to be a fair estimation at least for the order of magnitude.